# Webgl - use one program to mask out the previous program

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

Im running a shader program that renders out some vertices and then of course colours them in the fragment shader.

I then have another program running which i'd like to use to mask out a shape from the previous render.

So far the first one renders something like this:

```
animate_() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate_());

    this.gl_.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    this.gl_.clear(webgl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    this.gl_.useProgram(this.program_);

    // Runs enableVertexAttribArray, bindBuffer, vertexAttribPointer
    renderBufferAttribute(this.gl_, this.position_);

    // Pass through all my uniforms here
    // ...

    // Draw triangles
    this.gl_.drawArrays(webgl.TRIANGLES, 0,
        this.particleCount_.total * PARTICLE_ARRAY_COUNT / 2);
}
```

I then have a second program rendering like this:

```
animate_() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate_());

    // this.gl_.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // this.gl_.clear(webgl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    this.gl_.useProgram(this.program_);

    renderBufferAttribute(this.gl_, this.position_);

    this.gl_.drawArrays(webgl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

Ive tried setting the opacity in all directions in the fragment shader and then using gl.clearColor and gl.clear above but it either clears the entire thing or sets it as a color.

I then also tried only rendering over half of the canvas in the vertex shader for the second program but still cant find the solution.

Also using these on both programs:

```
this.gl_.blendFunc(webgl.SRC_ALPHA, webgl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
this.gl_.enable(webgl.BLEND);
```

Is this even possible?

**EDIT**

I'd also need to fade the edges of the mask.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of shape do you want to render in the second pass?

Comment: Any 2D vector shape that ill draw out but with faded edges.
What ill try do now is swap the order around and render the shape into a texture as an alpha map and pass that into the first program

Answer (score 0):

Whats better that removing pixelcolors from a fragmentshader? -> it's not calling the fragementshader at all.

You might read more about [stencilFunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/stencilFunc) which works like a stencil and discards the call of the fragment shader. Therefor showing the colors 'underneath'

Or [here](https://open.gl/depthstencils) for some opengl variants.

Comment: That looks like it would just about work! But (i failed to mention) i actually need to also fade the edges of the mask. Can the stencil buffer take float values or is it strictly ones and zeros to either show or hide?